# MySQL - Authentication (but only some of the time)

Tags: mysql, authentication, windows-server-2012

I'm getting the following error now and again.

> Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.

I know that the connection string is correct - first it's tested once the application is started and if it fails the application gives a message and exits.

Secondly the functions that are reporting it also are using it to connect correctly most of the time, its just happening every now and again.

I've tried changing to 127.0.0.1 but it didn't seem to make a different.

It's on a Windows Server 2012 64 bit.

I've addded 127.0.0.1 localhost to the host file.

99% of the time the application is running correctly and connecting to the database, just every now and again it gives this error.

On top of that I've checked the show full processlist command and I only have a few connections at any time.

I'm lost to explain this and can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but since I just found out the solution to this problem I'll share it just in case someone is still looking for it (as far as I can say this is a problem with current Mysql releases too).

This kind of problem is documented in [this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72110).

I'm quoting here the most important answer on that bug report:

> [21 May 2014 15:40] Francisco Alberto Tirado Zavala
>
> Hello Jorge.
>
> When you are working with a Client-Server application all the
>   connections are performed by Sockets, when you create a connection you
>   open a Socket between your client and your server, and an Id/ProccesId
>   is assigned/reserved in the server for the connection requested by the
>   client. If the server is restarted the Id given to the client is lost,
>   so you need to create a new valid connection opening a new socket to
>   get a valid Id from the server.
>
> Also you must consider that the server can terminate or close a
>   connection if the connection is inactive after some time. If you have
>   your connection open also could affect your connections pool, because
>   a connection open means less connections for your pool: having 10
>   clients connected at the same time are 10 connection less from the
>   Server available connections.
>
> If you can't change the design in your application (having a global
>   connection), as a workaround you can have a method to validate that
>   the connection is valid, for example the following method ping the
>   server and if the ping fails it open the connection again:

```
....
MySqlConnection _conn = new MySqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
private void CheckConnection()
{
   if(!_conn.Ping())
   {
     _conn.Open();
   }
}
....
```

> As you can see the code is very simple and it works in the following
>   way: when the connection try to ping the server if the connection is
>   invalid, internally the stream that has the socket information will be
>   terminated and the connection will be set on status closed as well as
>   the invalid connection will be removed from the connections pool if
>   exists, then opening the connection again will create a new connection
>   which means a new valid socket. If the ping succeed so you will
>   continue using the same connection.
>
> To use it you can call it before trying to perform an action to the
>   database, and the connection will be re-opened just when is invalid:

```
....
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //assuming that the connection is already open
  CheckConnectionState();
  var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select 1", _conn);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
....
```

> This is just a workaround, and as far I know all the connections to
>   any database server will have the same behavior: if the server is
>   restarted any connection will be lost, as well as the server will
>   clean every unused connection.
>
> Thanks for your time.